# Praise, Ibaadat, Worship, is there any difference?

Tags: terminology, definitions, ibadah

What is the difference between Praise, Ibaadath, Worship?

Answer (score 1):

Worship is translation of Ibaadah. Praising Allah is a type of worship. Praising is worship, but there are other acts that are worship but are not praising like zakat, sawm, udhiyah.